# Pig replace command

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have one file that has data like

```
11/16/2015,"others (phone,health,etc.)",cont'd attempts,"resource,inc.",dg
```

I want to remove comma's present only inside double quotes.

Expected Result

```
11/162015,"others(phone health etc.)",cont'd attempts,"resource inc.",dg
```

So far what I tried

```
Foreach a generate replace ($1,',',''); 
Foreach a generate regex_extract($1,'[\,]+',1);
```

But none of them work.

Comment: Can you give ud the output that you want ??

Comment: I want the output as

Comment: I want the output as  11/162015,"others(phone health etc.)",cont'd attempts,"resource inc.",dg

Comment: Is answer correct ? @Jigyasa

Answer (score 0):

Frist of all use **REGULAR EXP** to separate field in the tuple and then apply the **REPLACE**

Try this code :

```
a = load '<path>' as line;

b = foreach a generate FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line,'(.*)[,]["](.*)["][,](.*)[,]["](.*)["][,](.*)'));

c = foreach b generate $0,REPLACE($1,',',' '),$2,REPLACE($3,',',' '),$4;
dump c;
```

Answer (score 0):

can be achievable using a UDF, which can look at all fields in each of the tuple passed.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Long;
import java.lang.Exception;

import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataBag;
import org.apache.pig.data.BagFactory;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataType;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.Schema;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException;
import org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException;

public class CommaRemove extends EvalFunc<DataBag> {

    @Override
    public DataBag exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            int inputSize = input.size();
            Tuple output = TupleFactory.getInstance().newTuple(inputSize);
            for( int i = 0; i < inputSize ; i++)
            {
                output.set(i, input.get(i).replace(',',''));
            }
            return output;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to process input; error - " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rahul    But for line output.set(i, input.get(i).replace(',',''));  i am getting invalid character constant